# Careers 2.0 mocking my poor answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, email

I just got an email from Careers 2.0:

> We're impressed by your "r" tag answers on Stack Overflow.

I've written [two answers, with 0 and 1 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012620/andreas). Maybe the algorithm should be tweaked so it's a bit harder to impress it?

Edit: Oh, and I accepted both of them myself.

Comment: Careers 2.0... Always trying to find *something* nice to say.  ;)

Comment: And it looks like you'll be hearing from them about your "careers" tag questions, soon, too.

Comment: Did you complete the signup? Did it finish with a "Thanks for that, but we were just kidding"?

Comment: The AI makes jokes, now ?

Comment: I think the algorithm must be centered around your avatar, your nick's second letter, the TLD of your email address, or maybe `std::rand()`. Back when I had >50k rep and was among the top 10 of [a popular tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers), I only got an invite when some fellow in the chat (by then <10k, IIRC) who already got an invitation out of the blue suggested me to the team.

Comment: Pretty sure the threshold is based on rep, not answer votes, and the blurb is just fluff generated based on your top tag

Comment: @sbi I have to assume that you've found your way onto the team's super-secret list of agitators, rabble-rousers, malcontents and other undesirables. Then, when you were nominated, they had to play it off like excluding you was just an oversight, lest they face the wrath of the united C++ coders front.

Comment: @BenBrocka: [I doubt it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157133/careers-2-0-mocking-my-poor-answers/157135#comment453249_157133).

Comment: So @WillCole, what have you actually planned for this?

Answer (score 12):

We've re-calibrated the robots to not be so easily impressed in the future.  They will, however, occasionally thank you for your input before inviting you to join.

The next time we tell you we're impressed, rest assured that we mean it.